# trying to create a sequential ID variable for breeds in netlogo

Tags: variables, netlogo, turtle-graphics

There is probably a very simple solution to this, but I am having trouble coming up with it since I'm still pretty new to netlogo. I'd be very grateful for any suggestions. My model has multiple breeds of turtles with different numbers of turtles in each breed set by sliders. To make it easier to set some breeds-own variables later in the model, I want to create separate sequential ID variables for each breed. These would basically be like who numbers, but would run from 0 to n for each breed. So, let's say I create male and female breeds like this:

```
breed [males male]
breed [females female]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-breeds
  set-id
  ask turtles [setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  reset-ticks
end

to create-breeds
  create-males number-males [set color yellow] 
  ask males [set shape "circle"]
  create-females number-females [set color yellow] 
  ask females [set shape "circle 2"]
end

to set-id
...
end
```

I then want to run a "set-id" procedure that will create a male id var that will number the male turtles from 0 to male n, and another female id var that will number the female turtles from 0 to female n. I am assuming the solution should include some combination of foreach or n-values, but I'm having a lot of trouble nailing it down exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Don't do it!

I'm pretty sure it won't "make it easier to set some breeds-own variables later in the model". Using `who` numbers is error prone enough as it is without adding another separate index on top of it. (You shouldn't use `who` numbers either: there is almost always a better way to do things.) I'd suggest you ask another, separate, question and tell us why you think you need that and what you plan to do with it. I'm confident that someone will be able to suggest an alternative approach.

#### That being said...

You are right that a combination of [`foreach`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach) and [`n-values`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-values) would do the trick.

Assuming you have:

```
males-own [ id ]
females-own [ id ]
```

You can use the following procedure:

```
to set-id-for [ breed-agents ]
  (foreach (sort breed-agents) (n-values count breed-agents [?]) [ 
    ask ?1 [ set id ?2 ]
  ])
end
```

By using parenthesis around `foreach`, you can pass it as many lists as you like: it will "zip" them together and give you variables like `?1`, `?2`, etc., to address elements of each list. In our case, the first list is the agents and the second list is indices generated with `n-values`.

Call the procedure once for each breed:

```
set-id-for males
set-id-for females
```

Supposing you have created 10 males and called `set-id-for males`, you can verify that it worked using the command center:

```
observer> show sort [id] of males
observer: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

But please...

#### ...don't do it.

Comment: Nicolas, Thank you so much for the reply. I'll write another question. But, could you please explain how who numbers are error prone so that I don't misuse them?

Comment: I'll be happy to do that. I've been meaning to write up something about that for a while anyway. But it probably won't be in the next few days, as I'm moving abroad this week-end and won't have much time in front of the computer...

Comment: Good luck with you move.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you create a global variable and you use it inside of create male/female procedures:

```
globals [id]
breed [males male]
breed [females female]
males-own [id-male]
females-own [id-female]    

to setup
  clear-all
  create-breeds
  ask turtles [setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  reset-ticks
end

to create-breeds
  set id 0
  create-males number-males 
  [
    set id-male id
    set color yellow
    set shape "circle"
    set id id + 1
  ] 
  set id 0
  create-females number-females 
  [
    set id-female id 
    set color yellow
    set shape "circle 2"
    set id id + 1
  ] 
end
```

And you can include the "set shape" inside of create procedure.