# Netlogo - Turtles on more than one Patch - Item vs Who

Tags: indexing, netlogo

How are you? I guess there is no way to visually represent in the Netlogo Interface a system with a "many-to-many" relationship, where turtles belong to more than one patch, and of course patches host more than one turtle. Correct?
I have a model where Banks (my turtles) operate on more than one Country (my patches). So I think my only option is to have two breeds of turtles, i.e. Banks and Countries, and connect Banks to Countries with link agents. Correct?
(I will also need interbank links, so I will need to set up a different breed of links. Correct?)
Now: I need to identify countries by *name* (i.e. Italy, France, Spain, etc.). I am reading a CSV file with country names and feeding it into a Netlogo list, but I am not sure how to have a country agent "be" a name. I created a country breed-specific variable called "country-name", and I am trying to use "item" to sequentially access each *next* name in the list of country names and assign it to the country-name variable of the *next* country agent in the Countries breed. However, I cannot relate "item" to "who" here, because "who" is not breed-specific. So I am thinking of setting up a separate breed-specific numbered index, but something like this has been asked in a previous question ([trying to create a sequential ID variable for breeds in netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733897/trying-to-create-a-sequential-id-variable-for-breeds-in-netlogo)) and it was strongly suggested NOT to do so. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: I think that the SO guideline to keep questions to one single (and reproducible, if possible) programming problem is very pertinent to this case. This question refers to many topics and contains many open-ended sub-questions, and also we don't know how your model is set up and how you intend to use your agents. Narrowing down your question and illustrating both what you have and what you want to achieve would address most of the problems above and help a lot with being able to elaborate a precise answer. You could consider editing this post or deleting it and creating a new one from scratch

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment by Matteo.   That said,

You don't ever need to use "who".   Identify your banks and your countries with a "name" field that the breed owns.    For example

```
banks-own [ name ]
counties-own [ name ]
;; then somewhere in your loop as you read them in...
create-banks 1 [ set name "Chase" ... ]
create-countries 1 [ set name "England" ...]
```

Below I use 'one-of' but there will only be one hit.
This makes the syntax work converting a list item to a specific turtle.
You never should need to know or care about the "who" value of a bank
or country.

```
to make-branches
    ;;  read this list in from a csv file, etc. or hard code it
    set branchlist [[ "Lloyds" "England"] ["Lloyds" "France"] [ "Chase" "USA"]["Chase" "France" ]]   
       ;; then work the list. Again, you never need "who".
   foreach branchlist [ 
            z ->  ask one-of banks with [name = item 0 z ] 
            [ create-link-with one-of countries with [ name = item 1 z ]]
        ]
end
```